# Clickable td field and showing menu options

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've created a table, and want the dots to be clickable and then show a menu with two clickable options. But I'm trying to figure out how this could be done?
To make the text inside the `<td>` clickable I could do something like `<a href="#">...</a>` I think, but how can I make the clickable menu show under it?

I've posted the code here:

```css
.wdc_jql_table{
    /* table width */
    border:1;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    table-layout:fixed; // Cells is fixed to the percentage the cells is assigned too
    word-wrap:break-word;
    color: white;
}

.wdc_jql_table thead, tr{
    /* table style - bottom borders to seperate rows */
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #3A3B41;
}
.wdc_jql_table tr:last-child{
    /* table style - no border at last row */
    border-bottom: none;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2), 
th:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(4){
    /* table child th align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2), 
td:nth-child(3){
    /* table child td align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wdc_jql_table
td:nth-child(4){
    /* table child td align (...) */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.wdc_jql_col1{
    /* table col(project name) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col2{
    /* table col(owner) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col3{
    /* table col(jql) width */
    width: 50%;
}

.wdc_jql_col4{
    /* table col(...) width */
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<table id="others_jql" class="wdc_jql_table padding_jql_bottom">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col1">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col2">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col3">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col4">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>JQL</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody id="table_body_others">
        <tr id="<?php echo $wdc_jql_other[$i]['wdc_jql_id']; ?>">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td1</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td2</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td3</td>
            <td name="edit_other">&#8942;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="<?php echo $wdc_jql_other[$i]['wdc_jql_id']; ?>">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_other">&#8942;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image: card]

**EDIT: I now have a menu, but it doesn't align with row**

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.wdc_jql_table{
    /* table width */
    border:1;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    table-layout:fixed; // Cells is fixed to the percentage the cells is assigned too
    word-wrap:break-word;
    color: white;
}

.wdc_jql_table thead, tr{
    /* table style - bottom borders to seperate rows */
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #3A3B41;
}
.wdc_jql_table tr:last-child{
    /* table style - no border at last row */
    border-bottom: none;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2), 
th:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(4){
    /* table child th align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2), 
td:nth-child(3){
    /* table child td align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wdc_jql_table
td:nth-child(4){
    /* table child td align (...) */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.wdc_jql_col1{
    /* table col(project name) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col2{
    /* table col(owner) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col3{
    /* table col(jql) width */
    width: 50%;
}

.wdc_jql_col4{
    /* table col(...) width */
    width: 10%;
}

/* MENU DESIGN */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #8D90A1;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<table id="others_jql" class="wdc_jql_table padding_jql_bottom">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col1">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col2">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col3">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col4">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>JQL</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody id="table_body_others">
        <tr id="<?php echo $wdc_jql_other[$i]['wdc_jql_id']; ?>">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td1</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td2</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td3</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="<?php echo $wdc_jql_other[$i]['wdc_jql_id']; ?>">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="<?php echo $wdc_jql_other[$i]['wdc_jql_id']; ?>">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this only can be done with Javascript or any other scripting languange.

Comment: @Demeteor JS is totally fine, that's also why i tagged it in the question, because I thought the same

Comment: @Demeteor I've created the menu card now, but I have some alignment issues, maybe you can see what the problem is? (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create something like that:

Add class="edit_other" for each dropdown component. Then:

```
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".edit_other");
let container = document.createElement("div");
container.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
container.classList.add("dropdown__container");
dropdown.appendChild(container);

let optionsContainer = document.createElement("div");
optionsContainer.classList.add("dropdown__options-container");
dropdown.appendChild(optionsContainer);
let optionDivs = [];

let optionDiv = document.createElement("div");
optionDiv.innerHTML = options[i].innerHTML;
optionDiv.classList.add("dropdown__option");
optionsContainer.appendChild(optionDiv);
optionDivs.push(optionDiv);
```

That are basically containers and option divs for your select component:

```
<select name="dropdown-menu">
    <option>Edit</option>
    <option>Remove</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps. You can build on top of that.

Comment: I will try it out, and type back, thanks!

Comment: Might use something like this: `https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp` and when some of the fields are clicked some JS listeners will be trigged.

Comment: Exactly. You can also create a divs through the js. And add onclick events and that's it :)

Comment: maybe you can help me, but how can I make the menu align with the row? see my edit -> **EDIT: I now have a menu, but it doesn't align with row**

Comment: If your dropdown-content has position absolute you can adjust its position via top: X, left: X etc...

Comment: Okay, thanks! Will try to see if I can align them

Comment: It was just the javascript :)

Comment: nice :) let me know if you face any other problem